# Array.find() is returning undefined and I can't figure out why

Tags: reactjs, find, undefined

In my React project, I have a page that is reading a param called "itemId" and fetching from a list of items the one item that has id === itemId. My code so far is the following. (Ellipsis "..." means code omitted for brevity.)

App.js

```
...
const App = () => {
  const tempItems = [
    {
      id: 1
      ...
    },
    ...
  ];

  const Routes = (
    <Routes>
      ...
      <Route path="/item/:itemId" element=<Item items={tempItems}/> exact/>
      ...
    <Routes/>
  );
};
...
```

Item.js

```
const Item = ({items}) => {
  let {itemId} = useParams();
  console.log("Item id: " + itemId);
  console.log(items);
  const item = items.find((i) => i.id === itemId);
  console.log(item);
  if (item === undefined) {
    console.log("redirected because item with id " + itemId + " doesn't exist");
    return <Navigate to="/"/>
  }
  console.log("rendering item page");
  return (    
    <div>
      <h1>Rendering item page</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I enter "localhost:3000/item/1", the following console logs are printed. (Please don't ask me why all the item names are corn themed, lol.)

```
Item id: 1

Array(8) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
0: Object { id: 1, itemName: "Shepherd's Pie", itemType: "Cuisine", … }
1: Object { id: 2, itemName: "Cornmeal-Fried Fish", itemType: "Cuisine", … }
2: Object { id: 3, itemName: "Cornbread", itemType: "Side", … }
3: Object { id: 4, itemName: "Grilled corn", itemType: "Side", … }
4: Object { id: 5, itemName: "Corn Milk", itemType: "Drink", … }
5: Object { id: 6, itemName: "Corn Beer", itemType: "Drink", … }
6: Object { id: 7, itemName: "Corn Pudding", itemType: "Dessert", … }
7: Object { id: 8, itemName: "Sweet Corn Cake", itemType: "Dessert", … }
length: 8
<prototype>: Array []

undefined

redirected because item with id 1 doesn't exist
```

The itemId param in the URL is being parsed correctly because when I enter "localhost:3000/item/1" the console logs "Item id: 1". The items prop that I'm passing into Item.js is correct because it's printing out the complete array. But for some reason, the find function is returning undefined even though I know for a fact that the array contains an element where item.id === itemId (in this case 1). Is there some secret magic I'm missing? So far in learning React, it really seems like there's some confusing workarounds for confusing problems, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's some crazy solution that I'm missing that you can't just figure out with intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use `+itemId` to convert `itemId` string to a number in `items.find()`:

`const item = items.find((i) => i.id === +itemId)`

[Read more about `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)

Example:

```
// Here the itemId type is string so need convert it later
const {itemId} = useParams();

// Handle case if there is no itemId param
if (!itemId) return <Navigate to="/"/>

console.log("Item id: " + itemId);
console.log(items);

// +itemId will convert itemId from string to number
const item = items.find((i) => i.id === +itemId);
```

Full `Item.js` with these changes:

```
const Item = ({items}) => {
  const {itemId} = useParams();

  if (!itemId) return <Navigate to="/"/>

  console.log("Item id: " + itemId);
  console.log(items);
  const item = items.find((i) => i.id === +itemId);
  console.log(item);
  if (item === undefined) {
    console.log("redirected because item with id " + itemId + " doesn't exist");
    return <Navigate to="/"/>
  }
  console.log("rendering item page");
  return (    
    <div>
      <h1>Rendering item page</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I marked yours as the correct answer because I tried doing "const itemIdNum = parseInt(itemId);" and "const itemIdNum = Number(itemId);" and neither worked. Adding the plus sign before itemId as you said to do makes it work now. I knew the solution was going to be something super weird and random, lol. I'm having to learn React for a school project. At this point, I'm really missing Spring Boot and Java. It was so much easier and less confusing than React.

Comment: Glad it worked, I added a link for more about why `+` works, hopefully can make it less confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure item id is number not string

```
const item = items.find((i) => i.id === Number(itemId));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried your solution exactly but it still kept returning undefined. John Li's answer is the only one so far that's worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
let {itemId} = useParams();
```

Type of itemId in here is `string`. You need to parse it to Number before checking against your item list because I see that you have `id` as a number in your item list.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried "itemIdNum = parseInt(itemId)" and also "itemIdNum = Number(itemId)" and neither worked. John Li suggested putting a plus sign in front of itemId to convert it to a number and that's the only solution so far that works.

Answer (score 1):

you should convert `itemId` type to number before use it in comparisons:

`const item = items.find((i) => i.id === Number(itemId));`

or

`const item = items.find((i) => i.id === +itemId);`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just recently started learning React and Javascript. I'm coming from a Java background so errors like this are still stumping me all the time. I didn't realize useParams() wouldn't convert the param to a number for me.